# Mysql query Timeout issue

Tags: mysql

I have an application where a lot of options can be selected where there are four tables and possible 4 different terms from each filter and also additional for if we take value count and i am no good with queries just know how to get the desired result.So the queries can be like:

```
select distinct(maindbgroupid) from ((SELECT mainDBGroupID from 
groupstatisticsdata.seniority where ( `name` = 'Senior' )AND maindbgroupid in (SELECT 
mainDBGroupID from groupstatisticsdata.Function where ( `name` = 'Information Technology' 
)AND (`Value` >1000) AND maindbgroupid in (SELECT mainDBGroupID from 
groupstatisticsdata.Industry where ( `name` = 'Information Technology and Services' )AND 
(`Value` >1000))))) t join maingroupdb.campaigns on campaigns.groupid=t.maindbgroupid 
where campaigns.campaignName='Campaign1101'
```

This is one example , how to improve it please as i always get timeout when i use more than one filter.

What i am doing in the query is an intersect between the tables.

Comment: you are using a lot of ifs, you can prabably use join..

Comment: @confusedMind   this is really very confused  and robust code

Comment: @SashiKant That is what i would like to know, if there were only two tables i would have easily used join but not sure what to do here

Comment: @diEcho thats why i said i am no good with queries ...:|

Comment: @con atleast follow basic rules of writing a clean code. use CAPS for mysql keywords. indent properyly, use alias etc..

Comment: @confusedMind: Try my query, hope that will help, since I have removed all the in clause and joined every table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ::

```
select distinct(mainDBGroupID)
 from 
 groupstatisticsdata.seniority
 inner join groupstatisticsdata.Function on (groupstatisticsdata.seniority.maindbgroupid=groupstatisticsdata.Function.mainDBGroupID)
inner join  groupstatisticsdata.Industry on (groupstatisticsdata.Industry.mainDBGroupID=groupstatisticsdata.seniority.maindbgroupid)
inner join maingroupdb.campaigns on campaigns.groupid=t.maindbgroupid 
where groupstatisticsdata.seniority.`name` = 'Senior'  AND 
 groupstatisticsdata.Function.`name` = 'Information Technology' 
 AND `Value` >1000 
 AND maindbgroupid 
AND groupstatisticsdata.Industry.`name` = 'Information Technology and Services' )
AND 
groupstatisticsdata.Industry.`Value` >1000 
AND campaigns.campaignName='Campaign1101'
```

Comment: this does not look rite :| ...AND `Value` >1000 
 AND maindbgroupid ... As the and is to nothing....And it does give error